# How i manipulate two dates and update the third?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How I can subtract the field `todaytime` and the field `Timestamp` and add the result in days for 1 million objects in a collection? I need that for all the objects using Mongo shell.

My collection contains object like the next one:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5504cb8edd5af617ca9ca192"),

"Timestamp" : ISODate("2014-04-06T18:44:58.314Z"),

"todaytime" : ISODate("2014-04-02T01:11:18.965Z")}
```

Comment: Have you got any examples yuo have tried to run?

Comment: all of them gives me errors

Comment: You will need to do this by retrieving the document, performing the changes client-side, and then updating the document in the database. You cannot do it as a single MongoDB operation.